# Playwright: ReferenceError: browserContext is not defined

Tags: javascript, automation, hook, e2e-testing, playwright

I'm creating a new `browserContext`in the `beforeAll` hook to clear the `cookies`, `sessionStorage` & `localStorage`. This is working fine & the test is passing without issues. However, I am getting the error:  `ReferenceError: browserContext is not defined`...

**This is my spec file:**

```js
// tests/specs/login.spec.js
const { test, expect } = require('@playwright/test');
require('dotenv').config();

test.describe('Automates: CO-6367', () => {
  let browserContext, page;

  test.beforeEach(async ({ browser }) => {
    browserContext = await browser.newContext();
    page = await browserContext.newPage();

    await browserContext.addInitScript(() => {
      browserContext.clearCookies();
      localStorage.clear();
      sessionStorage.clear();
    });

    await page.goto(`${process.env.BASE_URL}/login`);
  });

  test.afterEach(async () => {
    await browserContext.close();
  });

  test('User logs into BO via URL with correct credentials', async () => {
    await page.fill('#email', process.env.BO_LOGIN_EMAIL);
    await page.fill('#password', process.env.BO_LOGIN_PASSWORD);
    await page.click('button[type="submit"]');
    await page.waitForURL('**/dashboards/main');
    const dashboardHeading = await page.locator('role=heading[name="Dashboard"]');
    await expect(dashboardHeading).toBeVisible();
  });
});
```

I'm not sure what's the issue here. I have added a screenshot for better context:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see additional line inside addInitScript which maybe cause of the issue.

```js
browserContext.clearCookies()
```

Lets try without this.

```js
await browserContext.addInitScript(() => {
      localStorage.clear();
      sessionStorage.clear();
});
```

The reason is the browser does not have access to the code running in node's scope.